# Express - route and rendering engine for every template file in nested directory

Tags: node.js, express, templating

Using Express Middleware [serve-index](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index/blob/master/index.js), a full directory can be [browsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2z5q.png) which in combination with [server-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js) allows images and text to be rendered (and other unrenderable binaries downloaded) when navigating to a file.

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path")
const serveIndex = require("./index");

const server = express();

server.use("/posts",
  express.static("./posts/"),
  serveIndex("./posts")
);

server.listen(8080);
```

I would like that when the file navigated to anywhere in the filesystem matches a given template file extension (e.g `.pug`, `.liquid` .. [Consolidate.js](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js/)) then an appropriate rendering engine should be used.

Normally there is a dedicated `views/` directory and individual routes created as needed but I wish to scatter template files across a filesystem to document different projects. The path in the url naviagted to using serve-index e.g `localhost/public/views/project-one` would be used to render the `index.liquid` template in that project's directory.

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path")

const server = express();

var { Liquid } = require('liquidjs');
var engine = new Liquid();

// register liquid template engine
server.engine('liquid', engine.express());

server.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

// route and file to return is hardcoded
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index') // render `index.liquid`
})

server.listen(8080);
```